# Jquery outerHeight for fixed position navigation when line wraps

Tags: jquery, navigation, height, word-wrap, css-position

I have a fixed position nav at the top of my website. I am using outerHeight to get the height of the nav container and then I am adding that as top padding to the container for the content below the nav. This all works well unless I shrink the window so the nav wraps to more than one line. In Chrome and IE outerHeight is still measured as if the line wasn't wrapping (works fine in Firefox).

JS

```
function contentTopMargin() {
    var topHeight = $('#topNavContainer').outerHeight(true) - 1;
    $('#container').css('padding-top', topHeight + 'px');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    contentTopMargin();
    });

$(window).resize(function() {
    contentTopMargin();
});
```

HTML

```
<header id="topNavContainer">
<nav id="topNav">

    <div class="current navItem"><a href="#1">item 1</a></div>
    <div class="navItem"><a href="#2">item 2</a></div>
    <div class="navItem"><a href="#3">item 3</a></div>
    <div class="navItem"><a href="#4">item 4</a></div>
    <div class="navItem"><a href="#5">item 5</a></div>

    <div class="clearDiv"></div><!-- for clearing floats -->
</nav>
</header>

<div id="container">
Some content
</div>
```

CSS

```
#topNavContainer {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
background: #333;
}

#topNav {
padding-top: 3.5rem;
padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 1200px;
width: 90%;
border-bottom: 1px solid #b1bdbe;
}

#topNav div.navItem {
display: block;
float: left;
margin-right: 4%;
font-size: 1.4rem;
}

#container {
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 1200px;
width: 90%;
padding-top: 7.5rem;
padding-bottom: 5rem;
}

.clearDiv {
clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call your function when the window is resized

```
$(function() {
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        contentTopMargin();
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add some of my JS in my question. I am calling contentTopMargin with both document ready and window resize. Also it's not the act of resizing the window that is the problem. If I reload the page when the window is small and causes the navigation to wrap the problem still persists.

Comment: @MJR do you have an example somewhere or a JSFiddle?